# How to create one-to-one relationships with declarative

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`, and I want `foo.bar_id` to link to `bar`. The catch is that this is a one-way one-to-one relationship. `bar` must not know anything about `foo`. For every foo, there will be one and only one `bar`.

Ideally, after selecting a foo, I could do something like this:

```
myfoo.bar.whatever = 5
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want a true one-to-one relationship, you also have to use the "uselist=False" in your relationship definition.

```
bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Bar.id))
bar = relationship(Bar, uselist=False)
```

Comment: This is not exactly right, because the ``uselist`` keyword has no impact if the FK of the join is in the same class than the relationship definition. See the [answer of chadwick.boulay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611874/851737) for the correct solution.

Answer (score 149):

The documentation [explains this nicely](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one):

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

OR

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child", backref=backref("parent", uselist=False))

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Note: The API and associated documentation has changed considerably since the answer was written. [New docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)

Comment: Those docs are like the least nicely written docs I've seen. They don't look anything like what you wrote! Yours makes way more sense. They used that strange mapped syntax and mapped_columns. I don't even know what those are lmao. Seems complicated.

Comment: @Zack, Thanks for letting me know the link to the docs is expired. I linked directly to older docs and provided a separate link to the latest.
By the way, if you aren't familiar already, the code from the `:` and before the `=` is a type-hint. This is typically non-functional, but it looks like SQLAlchemy is using it to infer relationships.

Answer (score 12):

I think if it is a truly one to one relationship we should add a uniqueness constraint to foreign key so another parent can not have other parent child!! Like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), unique=True)
    child = relationship("Child", backref=backref("parent", uselist=False))

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is actually quite easy. In your Foo model:

```
bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Bar.id))
bar = relationship(Bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers using `uselist=False` are correct, but in SQLAlchemy 2.0 `relationship` is now smart enough to deduce it if your `Mapped` annotation uses a non-collection type.

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one):

> New in version 2.0: The `relationship()` construct can derive the effective value of the `relationship.uselist` parameter from a given `Mapped` annotation.

Here is [chadwick.boulay’s code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611874/735926) modified for SqlAlchemy 2.0:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    child: Mapped["Child"] = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer(), ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

Notice how `child` is annotated with `Mapped["Child"]`, i.e. `child` is one `Child`. If you wanted to use a one-to-many relationship, you would annotate it as a list:

```
children: Mapped[List["Child"]] = relationship("Child", backref="parent")
```

Comment: For those looking at this solution with SQLAlchemy 2, be sure to check the docs (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) as you should almost always also set a database-level constraint to enforce that only one Child row may refer to a particular Parent row at a time.