# How to delete a one-to-one relationship with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to create a nullable, self-referencing relationship which can be deleted using SQLAlchemy. An example model is as follows (note, using Flask-SQLAlchemy):

```
class Person(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    partner_id  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), nullable=True)
    partner     = db.relationship('Person', uselist=False)
```

So think of this as a table of cops who have only a single partner, but that partner may turn out to have been in the mafia all along, so they lose their partner for a while. A cop without a partner is fine, at least in database terms - but I assume over the course of the show their partnerless status means a lot of property damage.

Needless to say, this question: [sqlalchemy: one-to-one relationship with declarative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464443/sqlalchemy-one-to-one-relationship-with-declarative/9611874#9611874) discusses how to set up this relationship. The question is how do you remove the relationship? Normally with a different foreign key you'd do this as follows:

```
joe.partner.remove(larry)
```

Where `joe` and `larry` are both `Person` objects. However, via the `uselist` argument, `joe.partner` is now actually a `Person` with no `remove` method.

Comment: person.partner = None?

Comment: just to clarify, `larry` got caught in the cross fire when the family had a civil war, so he needs to be out of the database. Will that delete the larry record?

Comment: Delete larry from the table as well?

Comment: As in delete poor Larry from the `person` table that is

Comment: Yep, as with the `remove` method.

Comment: think you need a `cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"` on the relationship. can't test it at the moment though, me computer is fscked

Answer (score 3):

How to delete one-to-one relationships is buried away in the SQLAlchemy documentation under the explanation of Cascades: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#notes-on-delete-deleting-objects-referenced-from-collections-and-scalar-relationships

> The delete-orphan cascade can also be applied to a many-to-one or
> **one-to-one** relationship, so that when an object is de-associated from its parent, it is also automatically marked for deletion. Using
> delete-orphan cascade on a many-to-one or one-to-one requires an
> additional flag relationship.single_parent which invokes an assertion
> that this related object is not to shared with any other parent
> simultaneously

So you'll want to set up your one-to-one relationship like so:

```
partner = db.relationship(
    'Person',
    cascade='all, delete-orphan',
    uselist=False,
    single_parent=True,
)
```

Then, deleting a Person's partner is just a matter of setting it to None:

```
some_person.partner = None
session.flush()  # will delete the partner object
```