# Creating one-to-one relationship Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am trying to create a one-to-one relationship between a `Department` & `Ticket` table. This way when looking inside of `Flask-Admin` a user would be able to see the `Department` name instead of the ID.

I have tried to setup the relationship as follows:

```
# Ticket Table
class Tickets(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tickets'

    ticketID = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    cust_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    cust_email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    cust_phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    tix_dept = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('department.deptID'))
    tix_severity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    tix_msg = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    tix_status = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    tix_recv_date = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    tix_recv_time = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # define relationship
    department = db.relationship('Departments')


# Department Table
class Departments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    deptID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    dept_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    dept_empl = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    dept_empl_phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

Then my `Flask-Admin` views are:

```
admin.add_view(TicketAdminView(Tickets, db.session, menu_icon_type='glyph', menu_icon_value='glyphicon-home'))
admin.add_view(DepartmentAdminView(Departments, db.session))
```

**Admin Panel for Tickets:**

[image: Department Admin View]

**Single Ticket Edit:**
[image: Department Dropdown]

How would I go about showing the `Department` name instead of the memory location?

Comment: For the one-to-one see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611874/6085135

Comment: `department = db.relationship('Departments', backref=backref("tickets", uselist=False))` the uselist=False might fix your view problems as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define function `__repr__` of `Department`.

```
class Department(db.Model)
    # ... column definition

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

The `__repr__` will show the name of department instead the inner representation of object.

PS: `uselist=0` is the key to define a one to one relationship in SQLAlchemy.